# GROUP BY making the query extremely slow

Tags: mysql

I'm running the following query which fails to show results after 10 mins.

```
SELECT
    t1.broker_name,
    t1.agency_name,
    t2.type,
    cmb.Centris_No,
    cmb.Price AS sell_price,
    cmb.Rent_Price AS rent_price
FROM
    brokers_global2 t1
        INNER JOIN
    brokers_to_listings t2 ON t1.broker_id = t2.broker_id
        INNER JOIN
    (SELECT * FROM all_mls_1_i UNION 
    SELECT * FROM all_mls_2_i UNION 
    SELECT * FROM all_mls_3_i UNION 
    ) cmb 
    ON 
    t2.mls_id = cmb.Centris_No
WHERE
    t1.agency_name LIKE '%String%'
        AND cmb.target_date > 20210101
        GROUP BY cmb.Centris_No
LIMIT 0 , 50000
```

The query works fine, but when I add `GROUP BY cmb.Centris_No` it comes to complete a halt..

As per another SO solution: I added an index onto the Centris_No column, I also modified the `target_date` column to **INT** instead of varchar and added another index on it.

But the result is the same.

Is there anything else I can try?

This is the create statement for all_mls_ tbls

```
CREATE TABLE `all_mls_1` (
  `Centris_No` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ST` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Mun_Bor` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Address` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Price` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Price_raw` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Rent_Price` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Rent_Price_raw` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CP` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `BT` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PT` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Lot_Area_Imperial` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Lot_Area_metric` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `region` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `latitude` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `longitude` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `district` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `target_date` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_added` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `MLS_INDEX` (`Centris_No`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The all_mls_# tables have about a 100k rows in total

Comment: add the execution plan to your question as well , but obviously index on Centris_No is not helping because it comes from a subquery of unions and seems like that part is the bottleneck in your query

Comment: you should include your `ddl`. for instance how many columns are there in `all_mls` tables? using wildcard on those will effect the performance, you're using only 4 columns from these tables.

Comment: What is the point of GROUP BY if you are not doing any aggregation?

Comment: @forpas it's just to show 1 result per unique Centris_No because there may be multiple unique rows but with the same Centris_No (if that makes sense)

Comment: It makes sense, but this way you get an arbitrary row for each Centris_No. If this is fine for you then you may change UNION to UNION ALL which performs better.

Comment: @RobertSinclair I'd change `SELECT * FROM all_mls` to `SELECT Centris_No, Price, Rent_Price, target_date FROM all_mls`, you don't need to select extra columns, that would make the query slower. and I'd also consider using `UNION ALL` if applicable.

Comment: @rasso thank you that makes sense, just added them and executed the query, also checked the execution plan as per eshirvana's suggestion and I see that the tbl brokers_to_listings has 50k records with no indexes which may also be a problem

Comment: @RobertSinclair no problem. mysql will let you use group by function even if you're not performing any aggregation. and you're not performing any:] I'm sure the query could be written differently, because this way it won't serve the purpose. someone will eventually rewrite it and post as an answer.

Comment: You have a typo in the last `UNION`.

Comment: @RickJames hi Rick, there was 17 tbls so I cut out a bunch of them before posting :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put it here since it doeasn't fit in comments.

two small things you can do to improve it a little bit:

1. use `union all` instead of union
2. in your subquery only select columns that you need:

```
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT Centris_No,Price,Rent_Price,target_date FROM all_mls_1_i UNION ALL
    SELECT Centris_No,Price,Rent_Price,target_date FROM all_mls_2_i UNION ALL
    SELECT Centris_No,Price,Rent_Price,target_date FROM all_mls_3_i 
    ) cmb
```

3. also look at your execution plan to figure our where the bottleneck is

Comment: your suggestion to use the execution plan is what let me identify the problem, can you put that in your answer please so I can accept. There was a table of 50k records that was getting checked and it had no indexes on it

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  t1.broker_name, t1.agency_name, t2.type, cmb.Centris_No,
        cmb.Price AS sell_price, cmb.Rent_Price AS rent_price
    FROM  brokers_global2 t1
    INNER JOIN  brokers_to_listings t2  ON t1.broker_id = t2.broker_id
    INNER JOIN  
    (
        SELECT  *
            FROM  all_mls_1_i
            UNION 
         SELECT  *
            FROM  all_mls_2_i
            UNION 
         SELECT  *
            FROM  all_mls_3_i
            UNION  
    ) cmb  ON t2.mls_id = cmb.Centris_No
    WHERE  t1.agency_name LIKE '%String%'
      AND  cmb.target_date > 20210101
    GROUP BY  cmb.Centris_No
    LIMIT  0 , 50000
```

- Have 1 table, not many UNION'd together.
- Instead of `SELECT *`, use `SELECT Centris_No, target_date, Rent_Price, Price`
- Use `DATE` or `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP`, *not `varchar(250)`*, for all date-related columns.
- Move `and add on`WHERE target_date > '2021-01-01'` into the derived table so that there is less to fetch.
- A `LIMIT` without an `ORDER BY` leads to random rows being delivered.
- A `LIMIT` of 50000 seems like a waste?
- Can `Centris_No` really be `NULL`?  I hope not.  If not, then promote it to be the `PRIMARY KEY`.
- Add `INDEX(target_date)`
- `brokers_global2` needs an index starting with `broker_id`.

(There may be more; fix these, the I will look at it some more.)

Comment: thank you! was a dumb mistake on my part as I didn't put indexes on the brokers_to_listings tbl which had 50k records in it. After I added suggestions in comments and your answer + indexes everything started to fly